# Nginx redirect to www

Tags: nginx

Again a nginx redirect problem. I need my website to be accessible only over https and always with subdomain www (or app or api). Is there a way the following configuration accept https://example.com (without www) ? Because that's what I see right now, without being able to explain why... I just add that there's no other server section on nginx configuration.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name ~^(?<subdomain>www|app|api)\.example\.com$;
    index index.html index.htm;
    return         301 https://$subdomain.example.com$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name ~^(?<subdomain>www|app|api)\.example\.com$;
    root /var/www/html/pathToMyWebsite;
    index index.php;
}
```

Edit: Here is what I ended up using thanks to @ivan:

```
# Redirects http://example.com & https://example.com to https://www.example.com
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;  # Here is the trick - listen both 80 & 443.

    # other ssl related stuff but without "ssl on;" line.

    server_name example.com;
    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name ~^(?<subdomain>www|app|api)\.example\.com$;
    index index.html index.htm;
    return         301 https://$subdomain.example.com$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen 443 default_server ssl;
    server_name ~^(?<subdomain>www|app|api)\.example\.com$;
    root /var/www/html/pathToMyWebsite;
    index index.php;
}
```

notice the "default_server" I added on `listen 443 default_server ssl;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, using regexp in the nginx config usually is not a good solution. Almost always it's more reasonable to copy and paste config blocks or use `include` statements since regexp introduces redundant complexity. Of course, it's kind of trade off what to use.

However, I have pretty the same usage pattern in my configs:

```
# Redirects http://example.com & https://example.com to https://www.example.com
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;  # Here is the trick - listen both 80 & 443.

    # other ssl related stuff but without "ssl on;" line.

    server_name example.com;
    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

# Redirects http://*.example.com to https://*.example.com
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name ~^.+\.example\.com$;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443;
    server_name ~^.+\.example\.com$;
    ssl on;
    # ...
}
```

Comment: I ended up using a mix of your solution and mine. I had to put `listen default_server 443;` because I had this error "no "ssl_certificate" is defined in server listening on SSL port while SSL handshaking"